# How to get Mimetype file id

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, mime-types

I Cannot get Memitype file id after creation, what I need to put created file id in as.getRange(i,11)
..........................................
details:-

```
function myScriptes() {
  var docFile = DriveApp.getFileById("ID");
  var tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID");
  var pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID");

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var as = ss.getSheetByName("invoices");
  var lastRow = as.getLastRow();
  



  for (var i = 2 ; i<=lastRow ; i++){
    
    var checked = as.getRange(i ,9).getValue();

    if (checked == true){
      var tempFile = docFile.makeCopy(tempFolder);
      var tempDocFile = DocumentApp.openById(tempFile.getId());
      var body = tempDocFile.getBody();
      
      body.replaceText("{invNum}",as.getRange(i,2).getValue());
      body.replaceText("{invDate}",as.getRange(i,3).getDisplayValue());
      body.replaceText("{dueDate}",as.getRange(i,4).getDisplayValue());
      body.replaceText("{clientName}",as.getRange(i,1).getValue());
      body.replaceText("{service}",as.getRange(i,5).getValue());
      body.replaceText("{amount}",as.getRange(i,6).getValue());
      tempDocFile.saveAndClose();
      var pdfFile = tempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
      

      pdfFolder.createFile(pdfFile).setName(as.getRange(i,1).getValue() + " - " + as.getRange(i,2).getValue());
      tempFolder.removeFile(tempFile);
    }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

[createFile](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createFile(BlobSource)) returns a [file](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file) so you can use [getId](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getId()) and store the id in cell `i,11`.

### Solution:

```
function myScriptes() {
  var docFile = DriveApp.getFileById("ID");
  var tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID");
  var pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID");

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var as = ss.getSheetByName("invoices");
  var lastRow = as.getLastRow();
  
  for (var i = 2 ; i<=lastRow ; i++){
    
    var checked = as.getRange(i ,9).getValue();

    if (checked == true){
      var tempFile = docFile.makeCopy(tempFolder);
      var tempDocFile = DocumentApp.openById(tempFile.getId());
      var body = tempDocFile.getBody();
      
      body.replaceText("{invNum}",as.getRange(i,2).getValue());
      body.replaceText("{invDate}",as.getRange(i,3).getDisplayValue());
      body.replaceText("{dueDate}",as.getRange(i,4).getDisplayValue());
      body.replaceText("{clientName}",as.getRange(i,1).getValue());
      body.replaceText("{service}",as.getRange(i,5).getValue());
      body.replaceText("{amount}",as.getRange(i,6).getValue());
      tempDocFile.saveAndClose();
      var pdfFile = tempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
      

      var file=pdfFolder.createFile(pdfFile).setName(as.getRange(i,1).getValue() + " - " + as.getRange(i,2).getValue()); // modified code
      
      as.getRange(i,11).setValue(file.getId()); // new code

      tempFolder.removeFile(tempFile);
    }
  } 
}
```